# Context Menu for ListView

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with a customized adapter in my application. I want to add a `ContextMenu` for deleting items in this `ListView`

in my `onCreate` method I register the `Context Menu`:

```
registerForContextMenu(lastCases);
```

where the parameter is my ListView

This should call this method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.i("onCreateContextMenu: ", "Inside"); 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.stock_file_menu, menu);
}
```

As you can see I use the Logger to log info whenever this method is called. But it doesn't outputs anything to `LogCat`, which indicates that this method is never fired off.

Also I should mention that my `ListView` is filled with information from this method:

```
private void RefreshCaseList() {

    lastTenCases = db.getAllCases(10);
    if (lastTenCases.size() > 0)
        error.setText("");

    lastCases.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(myClass.this, lastTenCases));

}
```

This method grabs some objects from a database, and fills the `ListView` with these objects, but this method is called before I register the `context menu` in `OnCreate`.

No errors does occure so I doesn't have any more information that can help me. Anybody how knows how to make a `Context Menu` for a `ListView` with a customized adapter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try putting your Log.i() line before the super.onCreateContextMenu(), or removing your super ? I'm not sure this one is required. Maybe it throws some "UnimplementedException" ?

Comment: Nothing appears to happend. I should mention that my class extends Activity and not ListActivity.

Comment: This should not be mandatory anyway... This page ( http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/ ) explains the whole process, but I didn't see anything that could be specific and different from what you do... :/

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

In my BaseAdapter I had to do this:

```
convertView.setLongClickable(true);
```